# Can't boot after converting lvm2 root to lvm2 raid1

Tags: boot, raid, lvm

I have Ubuntu 12.10 (no updates, kernel 3.5.0-17-generic) on first HDD (sda), which uses MBR and was partitioned as "Use whole disk for ubuntu" with LVM2 enabled. Root filesystem is on LVM2 (VG:ubuntu). Today I added second HDD (sdb) with same size, partitioned it like first hdd, created lvm2 PV and converted root LV to raid1:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb5
vgextend ubuntu /dev/sdb5
lvconvert --type raid1 -m1 /dev/ubuntu/root /dev/sdb5
```

After 100% resync I rebooted and initramfs was unable to find root fs:

```
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
... (kernel messages)
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root does not exist.  
Dropping to a shell!
```

There is list of modules:

```
(initramfs) cat /proc/modules
hid_generic
usbhid
hid
e1000
raid10
raid456
async_pq
async_xor
xor
async_memcpy
async_raid6_recov
raid6_pq
async_tx
raid1
raid0
multipath
linear
(initramfs) cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinux-3.5.0-17-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root ro
(initramfs) ls /dev/mapper
control     ubuntu-swap_1
```

There is output from `lvm` utility:

```
lvm> pvscan
  PV /dev/sda5    VG ubuntu   lvm2 [ 13.76 GiB / 408.00 MiB free]
  PV /dev/sdb5    VG ubuntu   lvm2 [ 13.76 GiB / 508.00 MiB free]
lvm> vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
  Found volume group "ubuntu" using metadata type lvm2
lvm> lvscan
  inactive        '/dev/ubuntu/root' [13.26 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE          '/dev/ubuntu/swap_1' [100.00 MiB] inherit

lvm> lvdisplay ubuntu
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu
  LV UUID                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2013-05-07
  LV Status              NOT available          <<<<< !!!!
  LV Size                13.26 GB
  Current LE             3394
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

And `lvchange -ay ubuntu` fails:

```
lvm>  lvchange -ay ubuntu
  /sbin/modprobe failed: 1
  Can't process LV root: raid1 target support missing from kernel?
```

What is missing from initrd?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hit this same problem on my Debian system; it turned to be caused by some necessary modules not getting installed in the initramfs.

Specifically, after adding these lines to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules:

```
dm_mirror
dm_raid
dm_region_hash
```

and running

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

my system boots correctly.

Note that I have not checked that all of these lines are actually necessary. I think the dm_raid module is missing by default at least.

After further searching, there is a Debian bug open against initramfs-tools over this issue: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=699804

Comment: Adding just the dm_raid and raid1 modules worked for me.

Comment: Apparently, from what I read, if you created your LVM mirror a while back (mine is really old, nearly 10 years...) then trying to use RAID1 just won't work. I tried many things and since I wanted to keep my `/home` partition, I couldn't try to start 100% from scratch.

Comment: A quick way to fix this is to install the `mdadm` package which installs the needed raid modules via /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/mdadm
In Debian buster for example the raid1 module is missing see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=841423

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `mirror` type instead of the `raid1`. That should work by default, even grub2 supports it. So instead of

```
lvconvert --type raid1 -m1 /dev/ubuntu/root /dev/sdb5
```

do this:

```
lvconvert --type mirror -m1 /dev/ubuntu/root /dev/sdb5
```

(You don't need to specify `sdb5` at the end, LVM will choose a suitable PV to put the mirror on.)

The mirror type has a big drawback though, it only reads from the first device, so you won't get the read performance speedup expected from RAID1.

Comment: Tobias, thank you. Where can I read about difference between lvm raid1 and mirror?

Comment: I don't know where this might be documented, I figured these things out myself empirically. (For example you can watch `iostat` while reading from a `mirror` lvm and see that only one PV is busy reading.)

Comment: The fact is that you still can't boot on a RAID1, which is why changing the type of mirror is the easiest solution to _fix the problem_. It's a "work around".